# How can I print side by side output in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to print output to a file in Perl in a similar way how `diff -y` works.

Sample output is like this.

```
     Master                                  Slave

node     -- canvas 1.0.3              | node     -- canvas 1.0.2
node     -- jquery 1.8.3.0.0.0        | node     -- jquery 2.1.1
yahooooo -- test 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0  | yahooooo -- test 1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0
```

The content in the Master and Slave columns is not in fixed length.

Tried this,

```
foreach my $row (sort keys %version_err) {
    format STDOUT =
    @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   @||||             @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    $version_err{$row}->[0]    $version_err{$row}->[1]    $version_err{$row}->[2]
.
write;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and describe the problems you are having.

Comment: Apologies, for not formatting the question. I am now trying Perl format. Will post you if I get error. Thanks for correcting my question.

Comment: That's fine. It's only a problem if you keep doing it! The rest of the community is here to catch any mistakes you make

Comment: I think `format` may be overkill for something like this. We could help a lot better if you showed the data structure that you wanted to display. Is it two arrays of strings, for instance?

Comment: It's a hash of array elements, please see the code above which I tried . Above code will not work with variable length.

Answer (score 3):

In these cases you should use a [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html).

Comment: Perl6::Form (Perl6-style forms for Perl5) are better than Perl5's builtin forms.

Comment: @ikegami Cool, didn't know that one yet.

Answer (score 0):

An option to format could be  [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table)

to get the data right you may need something like

```
use Text::Table;
my @table;
foreach my $row (sort keys %version_err) {
    push @table, [ $version_err{$row}->[0], $version_err{$row}->[1], $version_err{$row}->[2]];
    #or just: push @table, $version_err{$row};
}
my $tb = Text::Table->new("Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3");
$tb->load(@table);
print $tb;
```